# UITextView Not Allocating in View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I have been doing this awhile now and have run into a really strange error.  I have a view that contains a UITextView, but when I try to set the text after allocating the view, nothing happens.  If I stop it and look at the value, it is 0x0, which really doesn't make sense.  The components have been declared and connected in IB, so that's not the issue.  Here is the part that is giving me problems:

```
NewView *view = [[NewView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
view.label.text = string1;
view.textView.text = string2;
view.textView.editable = NO;
```

If I break it there and check the values, that's where it is 0x0.  That's why it's not loading, but I can't figure out why it's not working.  I have done this tons of times and have never seen this before.  Anyone have any Ideas what may be going on?

Comment: If it's connected in IB -- have you declared the property, and called `@synthesize textView`?

Comment: Yeah man.  That's why I am so confused.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but I was under the impression that the UI elements won't be initialized until `viewDidLoad:`? I would say pass it as a variable and try assigning it in the `viewDidLoad:` method?

Comment: That's a good idea, let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: That did the trick.  If you want write a quick answer, I will give you the credit.  Don't know why I didn't think of that first.  Good call and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was very simple.

Tejaswi pointed out that the UI components are not initialized until the viewDidLoad: method is executed.  So I passed the strings as a varaible and set the field text in the viewDidLoad: method.  This worked.